# How to generate tab delimited text file from flat text file

Tags: c#-4.0

I need write parser in c#

I get input txt file with following data.

```
A:1
B:1
C:1
************
A:2
B:2
C:2
**********
A:3
B:3
C:zzz
```

In this file each set is separated by `**`.
I want c# console application which will read this file and write another tab delimited text file with below format

```
A  B  C
1  1   1
2   2   2
3   3   zzz
```

Update
I've now whole data in one dictionary as below:

```
Dictionary <string, List<string>>my dictionary = new Dictionary  <string, List<string>>();
```

So values Im getting as

Key =A
Values =List of strings(1,2,3),

key =B,
Value =list of strings(1,2,3),

Key=C,
Value =list of strings(1,2,zzz)

Now i want it to display in tab delimited file or at least converted to datatable.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We will help you fix problems in your code, so you need to show us what you have tried and what is wrong with it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: First I created list by separating by ** Then I got list of 3 sets.  Then I added them into dictionary of string, list<string>. Now I'm trying to add this dictionary in datatable so that I can easily write it in tab delimited file. But not able to write dictionary into datatable first place

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have tried.