# Convert dictionary of string, list of string to datatable

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm having dictionary as below

```
Dictionary<string> mydictionary = new Dictionary<string>();
//Dictionary has below values

Key =A Values =List of strings(1,2,3),

key =B, Value =list of strings(1,2,3),

Key=C, Value =list of strings(1,2,zzz)
```

Now I want it to display in a tab-delimited file or at least converted to the data table. Here A, B, C are column headers

Comment: is that proper code that you are trying?

Comment: See https://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable for generation of a datatable.  Create your data table with column defs, then loop through all keys in the dictionary adding rows; using the list of strings to populate the column values.  If you can't figure it out from that, let us know what you tried / share your code and what you get stuck on.

Comment: No but I can't copy at this moment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate tab delimited text file from flat text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397244/how-to-generate-tab-delimited-text-file-from-flat-text-file)

Comment: @Dashing if people tell you a question isn't well written, improve it. As you see, this resulted in an even less appropriate answer